# string interpolation binding for desired format

Tags: angular, binding, interpolation

I have a string `str = "hello"+ "\n"+ "my"+ "\n" + "World"`.

html binding `<div>{{str}}</div>`

I expected to print this string as

```
Hello
my
world
```

I'm failing to do it but in console I'm getting what I want. Did I missing any thing here..

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5-example-kfrzue)

Comment: `<div style="white-space: pre">{{str}}</div>`

Comment: How about rendering in `pre` tag?

Comment: yea looks good.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35999185/1009922).

Answer (score 1):

Add `<br>` instead of `\n` and use `innnerHtml` tag in html

```
this.str = 'Hello' +'<br>'+ 'my' +'<br>' + 'world';

<div [innerHTML]="str"></div>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5-example-5xvp34?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: I'm using `str` for dynamic data, for each data I have different formats.

Comment: you can replace the tag with breaks like `str.replace('\n', '<br>')`

Comment: but for some reasons not preferring to use `<br>`